# Deprecation warning when converting moment from require to import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have been using `moment` within my React project previously by including it with `const moment = require('moment');` and it has worked without issue for as long as I can remember.

```
const moment = require('moment');
...
// expires_in is a string value somewhere
new moment().add(expires_in, 'seconds')
```

I'm doing a bit of uplifting of the code and decided to change it to `import Moment from 'moment'` and adjusted the usage to

```
import moment from 'moment';
...
// expires_in is a string value somewhere
moment().add(expires_in, 'seconds')
```

However, now I am receiving the warning:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged

I understand that, from the link on the warning message, that it wants me to specify a format of the moment so that there isn't any confusion.

But why is it only complaining now?

Comment: I doubt the error has anything to do with `import`  v `require`, but more likely the `require` is using an older version.

Comment: It just seemed odd that it didn't show up until now

Comment: Its about value you are passing as expires_in. To add time in seconds, you must get seconds as number from the string.
If you are passing date string, then you should use `moment(expires_in, "format you have it in");`